# Do I need to use autorelease on object which created not using alloc init?

Tags: objective-c, autorelease

I usually work using recent version of Objective C / Swift which already use ARC. But now I have to continuing the work on progress, which uses an old "situation" of Objective C, which happen to predates the ARC stuff. I have never learn about how to use `release` and `autorelease` properly, and now got confused and paranoid.

From what I learn, I can just use `autorelease` on any of my object initialisation, and not worry about the rest of it, just like if I use ARC. But recently, I began to think whether I also need to add autorelease to:

- object automatically created using syntax, which using `@` symbol.
- object returned from method and static method, such as `[UIColor redColor]`.

So now, I began to add `autorelease` each time I see any object creation. I even began to write:

```
NSString * data = [@"" autorelease];
MyClass * myClass = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
if (flag == true) {
    data = [[NSString stringWithFormat:[@"%@%@" autorelease], info1, info2, nil] autorelease];
    label.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] autorelease];
}
label.text = data;
```

Can you give me a simple rule of when I need or don't need to use `autorelease`, because all the `autorelease`s in my code starts to make me check my sanity of whether I'm doing the right thing or it's just my paranoia. Help!

Comment: There are countless existing discussions on memory management in Objective-C prior to ARC. Please do some searching.

Comment: @rmaddy I have read countless existing discussion about variable scope and autorelease pool, but I can't find one yet about object created from another methods or from objective c's `@` symbol. Or maybe I searched using wrong queries. But either way, my effort to do some searching was fruitless, which is why I wrote this question.

Comment: Do you understand when to use `release`? `autorelease` is essentially a delayed call to `release`. If you know how to use `release` you know how to use `autorelease`.

Comment: @rmaddy I know how to use `release` on an object I created myself (e.g. using `alloc` `init`), or a class variable. But I don't know how to use `release`  on object created by another method or by using `@` symbol, which doesn't preceded with `alloc` `init`. I was having many "overreleased" problem over this confusion, so I stopped using `release` except for the object I explicitly created myself, and began to use `autorelease`. But I don't know to what extend.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219575/objective-c-release-autorelease-and-data-types

Comment: @rmaddy so that means for every method is a convention to return something using `autorelease` so I don't need to add another autorelease?